# How can I fix Google Scholar inaccuracies

Tags: google-scholar

Until I told it not to, Google Scholar automatically added articles to my profile by scholars with the same name. I deleted those articles, but they still showed up on my university Google Scholar's page.

I have now deleted my Scholar account and had the university delete my Google account, but my university Scholar profile still pops up and it still seems to be "grabbing" works by scholars with the same name from other fields.
How do I just delete my Google Scholar existence entirely and start from scratch.  It's been over a year since I first deleted my account.

Comment: What do you mean by "university Google Scholar page"? AFAIK Google Scholar pages are only available for individuals.

Comment: My college has a search results page listing all of its Google Scholars.  Moreover, my GS account used the institutional web address.  This appears to have created a GS account in addition to the one I created. I deleted the one I created and asked my school administrator to delete the other. Sadly Google Scholar still generates a list of articles under my name and institution. This list inaccurately claims articles from other scholars with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asked in a bit of a chaotic way. Do I understand correctly?
Your university is pulling data from Google Scholar automatically onto your university page.
But you deleted your Google Scholar profile.
Yet the university website still lists your papers via google scholar?

That sounds like it's not being pulled from your google scholar profile that you had modified to only include your own publications but from google scholar directly.
I don't quite understand why your university is not using a better system. Surely, you cannot be the only one with similar issues?

Can you just have your own website where you curate your own pub-list?

To answer your last question, again a clarification question: so your google scholar account(s) were deleted but also not deleted? As in: when you google your name, there still is *your* google scholar page rather than just the pubs that are indexed on there?
Or do you just mean when you google your name in google scholar, your publications still pop up mixed with the other John Smiths?
It it's the former, that is odd  and should not happen. If it's the latter, nothing can be done. That's just indexing and it will be there as long as the publication venue you went with is indexed by google scholar.

Comment: @semmyk-research & Story, Thank you for your help.  The problem is that other scholars with my name cannot claim articles that they wrote because my GS account has already (without asking me) claimed them. I deleted the inaccurate listings of works from other scholars, but they still appear.  On my request, my school administrator deleted my college Google account.  I also deleted my personal account.  Yet this page still shows up. I would not care, but it "claims" articles written by colleagues with the same name in other fields. This is not fair to them.

Comment: Perhaps, your colleagues should go into their GS profile to add or edit the/their research entry/entries. ... That assumes the issues is from GS and not institutional RMIS/CRIS.

Answer (score 0):

> Until I told it not to, Google Scholar automatically added articles to my profile by scholars with the same name.

This is where you should have left it rather than the drastic action of deleting your Google Scholar account

> I deleted those articles, but they still showed up on my university Google Scholar's page.

Your university is probably pulling from (academic) sources and not just GS. Lots of universities uses RMIS (some refer to it as CRIS) to aggregate their staff and associates research outputs

I would suggest you include your orcid in your publications as this will identify you more uniquely (not completely foolproof).
Your orcid and GS profile might go a long way with your research presence. You have options though. You can even self curate into a personal website/page; hopefully, you don't get tied down into administrative *overload*.